# Alpine Linux - Failed to start discovery: org.bluez.Error.InProgress

Tags: bluetooth, alpine-linux, bluez

I am having problems getting bluetooth to work.

```
# uname -a
Linux alpine 4.19.98-0-vanilla #1-Alpine SMP Thu Jan 23 10:17:11 UTC 2020 x86_64 Linux
```

As you can see, hciconfig shows that the adapter is up:

```
# hciconfig hci0
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 5C:F3:70:62:65:B6  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
    UP RUNNING 
    RX bytes:2144 acl:0 sco:0 events:91 errors:0
    TX bytes:1111 acl:0 sco:0 commands:75 errors:0
```

bluetoothctl shows all seems ok:

```
[bluetooth]# show
Controller 5C:F3:70:62:65:B6 (public)
    Name: BlueZ 5.54
    Alias: BlueZ 5.54
    Class: 0x00000000
    Powered: yes
    Discoverable: no
    DiscoverableTimeout: 0x000000b4
    Pairable: yes
    UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    Modalias: usb:v1D6Bp0246d0536
    Discovering: no
Advertising Features:
    ActiveInstances: 0x00
    SupportedInstances: 0x05
    SupportedIncludes: tx-power
    SupportedIncludes: appearance
    SupportedIncludes: local-name
```

But whenever I attempt to enable scan I get the same error:

```
[bluetooth]# scan on
Failed to start discovery: org.bluez.Error.InProgress
```

dmesg shows a timeout with the tx command:

```
# dmesg | grep Bluetooth
[    2.709741] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    2.709758] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.709769] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.709771] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.709775] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    2.843398] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 63
[    2.847554] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x07
[    2.901177] Bluetooth: hci0: BlueZ 5.54
[    2.905321] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 0000
[    2.922080] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e8.hcd not found
[    9.240210] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    9.240211] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    9.240214] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  172.932277] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x200b tx timeout
[ 1150.828537] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2005 tx timeout
```

Everything seems to be alive and kicking, but it just refuses to enable scan, no matter how many reboots, or restarting bluetooth service, or power off and power on the adapter.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: If your adapter ID is 0a12:0001 and it is a clone (non-original), you are in troubles (like me). Check this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth#CSR_Dongle_0a12:0001

Answer (score 2):

As dirty workaround setting-up of discovery attributes working for me (Bluez 5.50 + RTL8192DU )

```
>hciconfig hci0 up
>hciconfig hci0 reset
>bluetoothctl
#menu scan
#transport auto
#back
#scan on
...
```

Comment: I had the same issue but I can't try this answer: I just got back the adapter to the shop where I bought it. I'll buy another.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue since I bought a new usb dongle for bluetooth. But I am able to connect after a random number of tries restarting the bluetooth service, powering off and on the bluetooth, trying to connect, so I created [this program](https://github.com/mageddo-projects/linux-bluetooth-connection-fix) to do this boring work to me.

Using it:

```
$ bluetoothctl devices
Device 94:CC:56:E5:72:85 WH-1000XM4
$ java -jar linux-bluetooth-connection-fix.jar 94:CC:56:E5:72:85
```

About the bluetooth issue root cause:

I wasn't able to find a real fix for the bluetooth problem, looks like it doesn't even exist, all people advise to buy a new hardware at the end, then I made this program as a workaround.

Related issues

- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=198718
- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=270693
- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=195886